# how to solve flutter white screen on startup

Tags: flutter, dart, screen, whitespace

I have an app and it was working, suddenly I clicked run and I have white screen with nothing, I didn't add any code from the last time, it was working till today,
here is my log

```
Launching lib\main.dart on BG2 W09 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
Uninstalling old version...
Error: ADB exited with exit code -1
Performing Push Install
D:\AndroidStudioProjects\business\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk: 1 file pushed, 0 skipped. 4.7 MB/s (63797998 bytes in 12.930s)
adb: error: failed to copy 'D:\AndroidStudioProjects\business\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk' to '/data/local/tmp/app.apk': remote No space left on device
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
D/SurfaceView(23749): checkSurfaceViewlLogProperty get invalid command
I/HwSecImmHelper(23749): mSecurityInputMethodService is null
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52457/m2CbTf6qGA0=/ws
Syncing files to device BG2 W09...
D/ActivityThread(23749): holder:android.app.IActivityManager$ContentProviderHolder@4e3f37, holder.provider:android.content.ContentProviderProxy@41ddca4
D/ActivityThread(23749): add activity client record, r= ActivityRecord{9f088b0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@d300329 {com.asmartcastle.business/com.asmartcastle.business.MainActivity}} token= android.os.BinderProxy@d300329
V/ActivityThread(23749): Performing resume of ActivityRecord{9f088b0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@d300329 {com.asmartcastle.business/com.asmartcastle.business.MainActivity}}
D/ActivityThread(23749): ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{9f088b0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@d300329 {com.asmartcastle.business/com.asmartcastle.business.MainActivity}}
V/ActivityThread(23749): Resume ActivityRecord{9f088b0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@d300329 {com.asmartcastle.business/com.asmartcastle.business.MainActivity}} started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: false
```

V/PhoneWindow(23749): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4 ,Parent =null, this =com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{ae1f10 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
D/WindowClient(23749): Add to mViews: com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{ae1f10 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}, this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@1a43141

```
D/OpenGLRenderer(23749): Dumper init 2 threads <0xa7392ec0>
D/OpenGLRenderer(23749): <com.asmartcastle.business> is running.
D/OpenGLRenderer(23749): Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: false
D/OpenGLRenderer(23749): CanvasContext() 0xb2ef3800
D/GraphicBuffer(23749): register, handle(0xa72147c0) (w:832 h:2048 s:832 f:0x1 u:0x000100)
V/ActivityThread(23749): Resuming ActivityRecord{9f088b0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@d300329 {com.asmartcastle.business/com.asmartcastle.business.MainActivity}} with isForward=true
V/PhoneWindow(23749): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0 ,Parent =ViewRoot{330f6e6 com.asmartcastle.business/com.asmartcastle.business.MainActivity,ident = 0}, this =com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{ae1f10 V.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
V/ActivityThread(23749): Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{9f088b0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@d300329 {com.asmartcastle.business/com.asmartcastle.business.MainActivity}}
D/ActivityThread(23749): ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{9f088b0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@d300329 {com.asmartcastle.business/com.asmartcastle.business.MainActivity}}
I/SurfaceView(23749): updateWindow -- onWindowVisibilityChanged, visibility = 0, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{e5e980c V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
I/OpenGLRenderer(23749): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer(23749): Created EGL context (0xa6c92240)
I/SurfaceView(23749): updateWindow -- setFrame, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{e5e980c V.E...... ......ID 0,0-600,976}
I/OpenGLRenderer(23749): Get enable program binary service property (0)
W/OpenGLRenderer(23749): Program binary service is not enabled.
I/SurfaceView(23749): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{e5e980c V.E...... ......ID 0,0-600,976}
I/SurfaceView(23749): Changes: creating=true format=true size=true visible=true left=true top=true mUpdateWindowNeeded=false mReportDrawNeeded=false redrawNeeded=false forceSizeChanged=true mVisible=false mRequestedVisible=true, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{e5e980c V.E...... ......ID 0,0-600,976}
W/OpenGLRenderer(23749): load: so=/system/lib/libhwuibp.so
W/OpenGLRenderer(23749): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/libhwuibp.so" not found
W/OpenGLRenderer(23749): Initialize Binary Program Cache: Load Failed
```

I/SurfaceView(23749): Cur surface: Surface(name=null)/@0xc41a07d, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{e5e980c V.E...... ......ID 0,0-600,976}
V/SurfaceView(23749): this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{e5e980c V.E...... ......ID 0,0-600,976} got resized: w=600 h=976, cur w=-1 h=-1
I/[MALI]Gralloc: dlopen libsec_mem.so fail

```
D/Surface (23749): Surface::connect(this=0x9afd7000,api=1)
I/SurfaceView(23749): New surface: Surface(name=null)/@0x4859b72, vis=true, frame=Rect(0, 0 - 600, 976), this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{e5e980c V.E...... ......ID 0,0-600,976}
I/SurfaceView(23749): Callback --> surfaceCreated, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{e5e980c V.E...... ......ID 0,0-600,976}
I/SurfaceView(23749): surfaceCreated callback +, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{e5e980c V.E...... ......ID 0,0-600,976}
W/libEGL  (23749): [ANDROID_RECORDABLE] format: 1
D/Surface (23749): Surface::setBufferCount(this=0x9afd7000,bufferCount=4)
D/GraphicBuffer(23749): register, handle(0xa7214b40) (w:600 h:1024 s:608 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
D/Surface (23749): Surface::connect(this=0x96052800,api=1)
W/libEGL  (23749): [ANDROID_RECORDABLE] format: 1
D/Surface (23749): Surface::setBufferCount(this=0x96052800,bufferCount=4)
D/GraphicBuffer(23749): register, handle(0xadbc43f0) (w:600 h:976 s:608 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
I/SurfaceView(23749): surfaceCreated callback -, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{e5e980c V.E...... ......ID 0,0-600,976}
I/SurfaceView(23749): surfaceChanged -- format=4 w=600 h=976, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{e5e980c V.E...... ......ID 0,0-600,976}
I/SurfaceView(23749): surfaceChanged callback +, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{e5e980c V.E...... ......ID 0,0-600,976}
I/SurfaceView(23749): surfaceChanged callback -, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{e5e980c V.E...... ......ID 0,0-600,976}
I/SurfaceView(23749): surfaceRedrawNeeded, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{e5e980c V.E...... ......ID 0,0-600,976}
I/SurfaceView(23749): finishedDrawing, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{e5e980c V.E...... ......ID 0,0-600,976}
V/SurfaceView(23749): Layout: x=0 y=0 w=600 h=976, frame=Rect(0, 0 - 600, 976), this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{e5e980c V.E...... ......ID 0,0-600,976}
I/Choreographer(23749): Skipped 70 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/SurfaceView(23749): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{e5e980c V.E...... ......ID 0,0-600,976}
I/SurfaceView(23749): Changes: creating=false format=false size=false visible=false left=false top=false mUpdateWindowNeeded=true mReportDrawNeeded=true redrawNeeded=false forceSizeChanged=false mVisible=true mRequestedVisible=true, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{e5e980c V.E...... ......ID 0,0-600,976}
I/SurfaceView(23749): Cur surface: Surface(name=null)/@0xc41a07d, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{e5e980c V.E...... ......ID 0,0-600,976}
I/SurfaceView(23749): New surface: Surface(name=null)/@0x4859b72, vis=true, frame=Rect(0, 0 - 600, 976), this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{e5e980c V.E...... ......ID 0,0-600,976}
I/SurfaceView(23749): surfaceRedrawNeeded, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{e5e980c V.E...... ......ID 0,0-600,976}
I/SurfaceView(23749): finishedDrawing, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{e5e980c V.E...... ......ID 0,0-600,976}
V/SurfaceView(23749): Layout: x=0 y=0 w=600 h=976, frame=Rect(0, 0 - 600, 976), this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{e5e980c V.E...... ......ID 0,0-600,976}
I/SurfaceView(23749): Punch a hole(dispatchDraw), w = 600, h = 976, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{e5e980c V.E...... ........ 0,0-600,976}
V/InputMethodManager(23749): onWindowFocus: io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{5e29555 VFE...... .F....I. 0,0-600,976} softInputMode=272 first=true flags=#81810100
V/InputMethodManager(23749): START INPUT: io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView{5e29555 VFE...... .F....I. 0,0-600,976} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@c0dfcbe controlFlags=#105
I/SurfaceView(23749): updateWindow -- UPDATE_WINDOW_MSG, this = Handler (android.view.SurfaceView$1) {deab11f}
I/SurfaceView(23749): updateWindow -- setFrame, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{e5e980c V.E...... ......I. 0,0-600,976}
I/SurfaceView(23749): updateWindow -- OnPreDrawListener, mHaveFrame = true, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{e5e980c V.E...... ......I. 0,0-600,976}
I/SurfaceView(23749): Punch a hole(dispatchDraw), w = 600, h = 976, this = io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{e5e980c V.E...... ........ 0,0-600,976}
D/GraphicBuffer(23749): register, handle(0xa72115e0) (w:600 h:1024 s:608 f:0x1 u:0x000f02)
I/flutter (23749): ar
E/flutter (23749): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 9, character 3)
E/flutter (23749):   "password": "Password",
E/flutter (23749):   ^
E/flutter (23749): 
E/flutter (23749): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1394:5)
E/flutter (23749): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:847:56)
E/flutter (23749): #2      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:31:10)
E/flutter (23749): #3      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:505:36)
E/flutter (23749): #4      JsonCodec.decode (dart:convert/json.dart:153:41)
E/flutter (23749): #5      DemoLocalization.load (package:business/Languages/DemoLocalization.dart:19:43)
E/flutter (23749): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (23749): #6      DemoLocalizationsDelegate.load (package:business/Languages/DemoLocalization.dart:41:24)
E/flutter (23749): #7      _loadAll (package:flutter/src/widgets/localizations.dart:58:49)
E/flutter (23749): #8      _LocalizationsState.load (package:flutter/src/widgets/localizations.dart:509:62)
E/flutter (23749): #9      _LocalizationsState.initState (package:flutter/src/widgets/localizations.dart:474:5)
E/flutter (23749): #10     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4640:58)
E/flutter (23749): #11     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4476:5)
E/flutter (23749): #12     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3446:14)
E/flutter (23749): #13     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3214:18)
E/flutter (23749): #14     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4527:16)
E/flutter (23749): #15     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
E/flutter (23749): #16     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4481:5)
E/flutter (23749): #17     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4476:5)
E/flutter (23749): #18     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3446:14)
E/flutter (23749): #19     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3214:18)
E/flutter (23749): #20     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4527:16)
E/flutter (23749): #21     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4675:11)
E/flutter (23749): #22     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
E/flutter (23749): #23     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4481:5)
E/flutter (23749): #24     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4666:11)
E/flutter (23749): #25     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4476:5)
E/flutter (23749): #26     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3446:14)
E/flutter (23749): #27     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3214:18)
E/flutter (23749): #28     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4527:16)
E/flutter (23749): #29     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
E/flutter (23749): #30     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4481:5)
E/flutter (23749): #31     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4476:5)
E/flutter (23749): #32     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3446:14)
E/flutter (23749): #33     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3214:18)
E/flutter (23749): #34     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4527:16)
E/flutter (23749): #35     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4675:11)
E/flutter (23749): #36     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
E/flutter (23749): #37     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4481:5)
E/flutter (23749): #38     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4666:11)
E/flutter (23749): #39     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4476:5)
E/flutter (23749): #40     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3446:14)
E/flutter (23749): #41     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3214:18)
E/flutter (23749): #42     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4527:16)
E/flutter (23749): #43     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
E/flutter (23749): #44     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4481:5)
E/flutter (23749): #45     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4476:5)
E/flutter (23749): #46     Element.inflateWidget (package:flut
I/flutter (23749): font = Cairo
```

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was 2 issue 1st language issue, when the app trying to call json translate file there was missing ((,)) but it wasn't show error, the second it was device space issue.
thank you for helping

Answer (score 1):

Try `Flutter clean` in terminal, then build again.

Answer (score 1):

**error no space left on the device**

```
db: error: failed to copy 'D:\AndroidStudioProjects\business\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk' to '/data/local/tmp/app.apk': remote No space left on device
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
D/SurfaceView(23749): checkSurfaceViewlLogProperty get invalid command
I/HwSecImmHelper(23749): mSecurityInputMethodService is null
```